# How can I express mathematically the set of elements contained by at least M of N sets?

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm aware that if I wanted the elements in 1 of 2 sets (i.e. $M = 1$, $N = 2$) I could use an intersection:
$$
S = A \cap B
$$
and if i wanted the elements in *at least* 2 of 3 sets (i.e. $M=2, N=3$), a combination of unions and intersections:
$$
S = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)
$$
but how can I determine the resulting set for elements in $M$ of $N$ sets with arbitrary values of M and N where ($M\leq N$)?

For example, if I have sets 
$$
A = \{1, 2\}
$$
$$
B = \{3, 4\}
$$
$$
C = \{5, 6\}
$$
$$
D = \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}
$$
and $M=2$, $N=4$, 
the result of these sets should be 
$$
S = \{1, 3, 5\}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either describe it with text, or use an index approach.
Let your $N$ sets be $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_N$.
Then the set you're looking for is

$$\bigcup_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_M\leq N}\left(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\dots\cap A_{i_M}\right)$$